# getting following error upon deploying application on tomcat 5.5

Tags: java, tomcat

Upon deploying an web app on tomcat getting the following error, Please advise which jar I am, missing in my classpath

```
ct 19, 2012 1:23:20 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1438)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3743)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4252)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:736)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:448)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:552)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:433)
```

Comment: Have you `spring.jar` or `spring-core.jar` in your classpath?

Comment: <classpathentry kind="lib" path="spring/spring-2.0.6.jar"/>

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs only when you are running a spring web application in an Eclipse managed with tomcat.

Please follow this steps,

```
1) Open the project's properties (e.g., right-click on the project's name in the project explorer and select "Properties")
2) select "Deployment Assembly"
3) Click the "Add..." button on the right margin
4) Select "Java Build Path Entries" from the menu of Directive Type and click "Next"
5) Select "Maven Dependencies" from the Java Build Path Entries menu and click "Finish".
```

I hope this will helpful to you.

Comment: I reach to step 4 but didn't find maven dependencies as Project is not maven one

Comment: ok..The reason is put  is not recogized librarys in folder.put spring.jar file in lib folder or your classpath and try.Else better idea is use build tools (ant or maven..).